# Is it possible to find all objects created with Ninject, registered as interface A, but implementing interface B?

Tags: c#, xamarin, dependency-injection, ninject

I have following problem.

Let's say we have following interface:

```
public interface IMyObserver
{
    Task<bool> OnSomeEvent();
}
```

And we have few services:

```
public class MyService1 : IMyService1, IMyObserver
{ ... }

public class MyService2 : IMyService2 , IMyObserver
{ ... }
```

etc.

They are bound like this:

```
Kernel.Bind<IMyService1>().To<MyService1 >();
Kernel.Bind<IMyService2>().To<MyService2>();
```

etc.

Is it possible to inject in a ViewModel constructor all instances implementing IMyObserver interface? Something like this:

```
public MyViewModel(IList<IMyObserver> observers)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried binding and resolving like this ?

```
Kernel.Bind<IMyService1, IMyObserver>().To<MyService1>();
Kernel.Bind<IMyService2, IMyObserver>().To<MyService2>();
```

and

```
public MyViewModel(IEnumerable<IMyObserver> observers)
{
}
```

Comment: Not yet. I'll try. Thanks.